# Update HTML dropdown list with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

This issue is making me crazy.
I would like to update a dropdown list (select options) named "Title" (having 2 options ("Mr" & "Ms").
If i run with this way (updating the select option outside the function), the dropdown list is updated selecting the option #1. Also the input field named "e1" is updated.

```js
var MyTitle = document.getElementById("Title");
MyTitle.selectedIndex = 1;

function bb(ff) {
  document.getElementById("e1").value = ff;
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(bb).FillUserDetails("gg");
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s1">
  <select id="Title" name="Title">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Ms</option>
  </select>
  <label>Gender</label>
</div>
<input type="text" id="e1" name="e1" class="validate">
```

But If i run with this way (updating the select option inside the function), the dropdown list is not updated  and still selecting the option #0. while the input field (e1) is update.

```js
function bb(ff) {
  var MyTitle = document.getElementById("Title");
  MyTitle.selectedIndex = 1;
  document.getElementById("e1").value = ff;
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(bb).FillUserDetails("gg");
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s1">
  <select id="Title" name="Title">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Ms</option>
  </select>
  <label>Gender</label>
</div>
<input type="text" id="e1" name="e1" class="validate">
```

Even using:

```
M.updateTextFields();
M.FormSelect.init(elems);
```

the problem persists. Any ideas?

I'm adding the code of the FillUserDetails() function.
in code.gs

```
function FillUserDetails(a) {
a="Hello";
return a
}
```

I hope this addition improves the clarity of the question.

Comment: Could you please edit your question, and add a code snippet (using the `[<>]` button), put in there the relevant JS and HTML, so we can witness the issue

Comment: @JeremyThille. Hope my update meets your requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's better, thanks. I made runnable snippets with your HTML + JS code. Since `google` is not defined, in the second snippet, `bb()` is not called, so nothing happens at all.

Comment: @JeremyThille -live code snippet is impossible here since OP is using an *outside* method which does not exist in the live code (`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler`)

Comment: @JeremyThille. I added a code of the FillUserDetails() function. This helps?

Comment: @vsync I know. My point is, if you call `bb()` manually, instead of `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(bb)`, it works. Gender "Ms" is selected. So, the diagnostic is, `bb` is not being called by `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(bb)` for some reason.

Comment: The bb() function is runned (The proof is that the input field (e1) is updated. Even if i call the bb() function manually, the select option is not updated. I don't understand why the select option is not update if the code is inside the function (if it's outside the function, it works).

Comment: @JeremyThille. I found the solution. in M.FormSelect.init(elems); the name of the select option was wrong. Thank you for your assistance.